Error building and installing custom python package
I'm trying to distribute my custom python package through GCP Artifact repository and use it in my project but got a dependent error.
pyproject.toml:
...
dependencies = [
  "pandas>=2.2.3",
  "numpy>=1.26.4",
  "sentence-transformers>=3.0.1",
  "scikit-learn>=1.5.2",
  "racplusplus>=0.1.1",
  "requests>=2.32.3",
  "vertexai>=1.48.0",
  "python-dotenv>=1.0.1",
  "gcsfs>=2024.10.0"
]

I build the package with the following command python -m build --sdist --wheel and upload it with python3 -m twine upload --non-interactive --config-file .pypirc --repository-url "https://${{ env.GCP_REGION }}-python.pkg.dev/${{ env.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}/${{ env.GCP_REPOSITORY }}/" dist/*
But when I try to install it with pip install mf-ai-subrequests==1.0.0 --index-url https://$GCP_REGION-python.pkg.dev/$GCP_PROJECT_ID/$GCP_REPOSITORY/simple/
Got the following error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas==2.2.3 (from mf-ai-subrequests) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas==2.2.3

Any idea how to solve it?

use --extra-index-url instead of --index-url

Instead of explicitly going for above "pandas>=2.2.3" you can mentioned as below and system will adjust based on other dependency.
pandas~=2.0.0
